# SendGrid: Error when trying to add scopes with the API

Tags: api, scope, twilio, sendgrid, twilio-api

I'm trying to add scopes to an API key with the API (actually to the same key I'm using to connect to the API).
I'm following the [example in the doc](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/api-keys/update-api-key-name-and-scopes), and my current scopes do include the `api_key_update` permission.

However when I try to add more scopes to the API key, I always receive a `400 Bad Request` error.

For example apparently this is the bare minimum of scopes when having set the "API Keys" permission to "Full Access" in the admin panel (retrieved via the `GET v3/scopes` API endpoint):

```
templates.read
api_keys.create
api_keys.read
api_keys.update
api_keys.delete
sender_verification_eligible
2fa_required
```

And when I now try to add a `mail.send` scope to it, I receive this error message:

`{"errors":[{"field":null,"message":"unauthorized scopes: [mail.send]"}]}`

When I just pass the already existing scopes, I receive a successful response. I can also remove scopes successfully by leaving them out of the passed array. But I cannot add them, no matter which scope I try to add.

I've tested with Node.JS and with curl, here are the curl test scripts:

```
Working:
curl -X PUT --header "Authorization: Bearer INSERT_API_KEY" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name": "INSERT_API_KEY_NAME", "scopes": ["templates.read", "api_keys.create", "api_keys.read", "api_keys.update", "api_keys.delete", "sender_verification_eligible", "2fa_required"]}' https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/api_keys/INSERT_API_KEY_ID


Not working:
curl -X PUT --header "Authorization: Bearer INSERT_API_KEY" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name": "INSERT_API_KEY_NAME", "scopes": ["templates.read", "api_keys.create", "api_keys.read", "api_keys.update", "api_keys.delete", "sender_verification_eligible", "2fa_required", "mail.send"]}' https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/api_keys/INSERT_API_KEY_ID
```

Comment: I was just able to add the `mail.send` scope to an API key I just created. Have you checked the permissions for the API key you are trying to use to update the scopes? API keys can have permission to read scopes or to update them, perhaps you only have read access for this API key?

Comment: @philnash
Do you mean the `api_keys.update` scope that I had specifically stated in my post?

Comment: Huh, I was looking at the scope you were trying to add, sorry. Are you able to do this with an API key that has full access, rather than individually selected permissions?

Comment: @philnash
I can already set all the permissions that an API key currently has, I don't see what additional permission I could try to add to an API key if it already has them all?

Comment: I’m trying to work out if there’s something wrong with the individual permissions when adding `mail.send`. And I’m on my phone right now, so I can’t test it myself.

Comment: @philnash It's not only `mail.send`, it's _any_ permission that I try to add that's not yet part of the already set permissions.

Comment: Are you trying to add permissions to the API key that you’re also using to authorise the request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245634/discussion-between-sp00n-and-philnash).

Comment: Saw the discussion, and reproduced the issue. Will raise this internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to the bottom of this.

An API Key with permission to update other API keys can only give permissions that the API Key itself has. That's why an API key with full access was able to update the scopes on another API Key, but your API Key with only a few permissions including access to update other API keys couldn't add other scopes. This also leads to the conclusion that an API key cannot give itself further permissions too.

This makes sense for limited scope API keys. The intention behind the limits are that you can limit the potential damage from leaking an API key if it can only perform certain actions. If you leaked a key and it was able to add permissions to itself, that would render the limited permission feature useless.

We accept that this isn't clear in the documentation and we have raised an issue to update the documentation so this is more obvious.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I ran into this same issue and did not understand why I was getting this error until I read this post. The why does makes sense. I agree the documentation did not make this clear or I might have missed it.